# How can I display author id on the author page

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to display the author id on the author page by using a shortcode I created but it's currently not working because the shortcode is only outputting the administrator id.
This is what I'm returning in the shortcode:

```
return get_the_author_meta('ID');
```

Comment: Can you post the whole shortcode please?

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
function author_id_shortcode(){
    ob_start();
    
    // We get the author ID outside loop.
    global $post;
    $author_id = $post->post_author;
    
    //  Now get the author ID inside loop.
    $author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
    
    $output = get_the_author_meta( 'ID', $author_id );

    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
    
}
add_shortcode( 'author_id', 'author_id_shortcode' );
```

call the shortcode with [author_id]

Comment: Thank you, that looks almost identical to what I had. Buy I changed everything to match your code and it's still returning the id of the administrator instead of the id of the author.

Comment: Kinda strange. Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code on author.php

```
if (is_author()){
    $author = get_queried_object();
    $author_id = $author->ID;
    echo $author_id;
}
```